# show/hide map, starting with a hidden map (display: none)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-3.1, gmaps4rails

I haven't been able to load my page with a hidden map that I can then Show clicking on :toggle_map_button

In my view a Show/Hide button and a map:

```
 <%= link_to_remote "Hide Map", :url =>{:action => :toggle_map}, :method => :get, :loading => visual_effect(:toggle_slide, "marketplace_map", :duration => 1, :queue => 'front'), :html => {:id => "toggle_map_button", :class => "toggle_map_button"} %>  

<%= gmaps(:map_options => {:detect_location => true, :center_on_user => true, :zoom => 6, :id => "marketplace_map" }, :markers => { "data" => @json }) %>
```

In my CSS file:

```
#maketplace_map
{
   width: 100%;
   height: 400px;
   display: none; <= this doesn't get to be set (when I check in HTML code with Bugzilla)
}
```

In my RJS file upon action :toggle_map:

```
page << "document.getElementById('toggle_map_button').innerHTML =(document.getElementById('toggle_map_button').innerHTML == 'Show Map' ? 'Hide Map' : 'Show Map')"

page.flash_msg(:notice_box, flash[:notice]) if flash[:notice]
page.flash_msg(:error_box, flash[:error]) if flash[:error]

flash.discard
```

The whole things works perfect when starting with a page showing the map. The toggle action does set display:none; correctly ...

The issue is comes when starting with a hidden map and be able to click and slide it down.

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Joel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look bit closer at the html generated, I bet it's looking like:

```
<div class="map_container"> 
  <div id="marketplace_map" class="gmaps4rails_map"></div>
</div>
```

so the adequate CSS lever is the `map_container` class. Put `display:none` on it.

---

since `visual_effect` seems to need an `id`, two options:

- override the gmaps4rails partial
- wrap the gmaps helper in a div: `<div id="foo"> <%= gmaps(bar) %> </div>`

---

I've got another solution for you, just tested.

You were right saying the map is small when hidden the visible.

so add an option to your helper: `<%= gmaps(whatever, :last_map => false)%>`

This will not create the map, only load it's objects.

Then add some javascript (I use jQuery but you've got the idea):

```
<script>
var createMap = true;
$(function(){
  $("#click_me").click(function(){ 
  if (counter == true)
   {
    Gmaps.loadMaps(); //this will create the map
    counter = false;
   }
  $(".map_container").toggle();  // this hides and shows
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: it is indeed! and display:none does hide the div (I had noticed that), but then AJAX special effect need to pass the id of the div you need to toggle... not a class name... that's what I have been trying to get my head around. I just don't manage. Hence my try on working with marketplace_map id... but then display:none doesn't not get set. Unless there is a way to pass a class name to visual effect (?) hm

Comment: you can pass class and id to whatever effects you want (at least with jQuery but prototype shouldn't be that different)

Comment: no luck with prototype so far visual_effect(name, id = nil, options = {}) I suppose I'll open a new question for this one

Comment: yes that was my very first attempts, but then the map doesn't show properly when I click on the show button it (toggle show)! It's really small and it is hidden in the top left corner of the div, the rest of the area is gray, and I dont even manage to zoom in. hence my attempt to work with the original containers. I'll try a little harder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4534/discussion-between-apneadiving-and-joelmaranhao)

Comment: please consider +1 too, spent much time on this

Answer (score 0):

resolved it thx to @apneadiving suggestion

added option:

```
:complete => 'Gmaps.loadMaps();' to visual_effect
```

In the view:

```
<%= link_to_remote "Show Map", 
    :url =>{:action => :toggle_map}, 
    :method => :get, 
    :loading => visual_effect(:toggle_slide, "map", :duration => 1, :queue => 'front'), 
    :complete => 'Gmaps.loadMaps();',
    :html => {:id => "toggle_map_button", :class => "toggle_map_button"} %>  

<div id="map" style="display:none;" >
    <%= gmaps(:map_options => {:detect_location => true, :center_on_user => true, :zoom => 6, :id => "marketplace_map", :last_map => false }, :markers => { "data" => @json }) %>           
</div>
```